# Weak star convergence of the averging operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\{T_k\}$ be a dyadic decomposition of $\mathbb{R}$, namely, the collection of dyadic intervals of length $2^{-k}$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the averaging operator
$$E_k(f)=\sum_{J\in T_k}\left(\frac{1}{|J|}\int_J f d x\right) \chi_{J},$$
where $f$ is nonnegative and $f\in L_{loc}^1{(\mathbb{R})}$.

Do we have $E_{k}(f)\to f$ as $k\to +\infty$?

(If necessary, we can let $f\in A_{\infty}$, where $A_{\infty}$ is the Muckenhoupt weight)

I guess and hope it is right, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Convergence in which sense? In any case, $E_k(f)=\mathbb{E}[f\mid \sigma(T_k)]$, so that you can apply martingale convergence theorems.

Comment: @MaoWao I think pointwise is enough. I am not familar to measure theory, could you explain the symbol in detail? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't expect more than a.e. convergence (and this is indeed true). The symbol $\mathbb{E}[f\mid\mathcal{F}]$ denotes the conditional expectation of $f$ onto the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$. Maybe someone will give an answer avoiding martingale theory, but it is really useful for questions of this type, so I'd suggest looking into it.

Comment: @MaoWao Almost everywhere is what I needed. I will find more materials about it. Thank you again for the clue. ^_^

Comment: Elementary martingale theory for infinite measures (such as the Lebesgue measure in your case) and with a focus on analytic applications is nicely developed in the book *Analysis in Banach Spaces*. Since you seem to be interested in harmonic analysis, I can only recommend it.

Comment: For pointwise a.e. convergence, Lebesgue's differentiation theorem applies here.